# Upload camera video feed to flask rest api

Tags: python, c#, flask-restful

I am trying to deploy a realtime image recognition system in python flask api then call it in a winform desktop application, what's the best way to send the video feed throug a json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send via base64 format inside json. But best way is designing flask api to expect multipart form data.Even json data + multipart is possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766072/post-method-to-upload-file-with-json-object-in-python-flask-app